# Required field validation not working in html step form

Tags: javascript, html

This step form is not validating the required field. the error most probably occurs in the next button. When I was able to validate the first field then the next button didn't work. I used a function checkvalue() to validate the fields. I have given both HTML and javascript part below ,  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```js
  <script>
    
      $(document).ready(function () {

            var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
            var opacity;
            var current = 1;
            var steps = $("tab").length;


           

            setProgressBar(current);

            $(".next").click(function () {

                current_fs = $(this).parent();
                next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

                //Add Class Active
                $("#progressbar li").eq($("tab").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

                //show the next fieldset
                next_fs.show();
                //hide the current fieldset with style
                current_fs.animate({ opacity: 0 }, {
                    step: function (now) {
                        // for making fielset appear animation
                        opacity = 1 - now;

                        current_fs.css({
                            'display': 'none',
                            'position': 'relative'
                        });
                        next_fs.css({
                            'opacity': opacity,
                            'display': 'block'
                        });
                    },
                    duration: 500
                });

                
                setProgressBar(++current);
            });

            $(".previous").click(function () {


                current_fs = $(this).parent();
                previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

                //console.log(current_fs.css)

                //Remove class active
                // $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

                //show the previous fieldset
                previous_fs.show();

                //hide the curren t fieldset with style
                current_fs.animate({ opacity: 0 }, {
                    step: function (now) {
                        // for making fielset appear animation
                        opacity = 1 - now;

                        current_fs.css({
                            'display': 'none',
                            'position': 'relative'
                        });
                        previous_fs.css({
                            'opacity': opacity,
                            'display': 'block'
                        });
                    },
                    duration: 500
                });
                setProgressBar(--current);

            });

            function setProgressBar(curStep) {
                var percent = parseFloat(100 / steps) * curStep;
                percent = percent.toFixed();
                $(".progress-bar")
                    .css("width", percent + "%")
            }

            

        });
        
        
        var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";
}

function checkValue() {
        var name = document.getElementById("orgame");
        if(name.value === "") {
          var att = document.createAttribute("required");
          name.setAttributeNode(att);
        }
    var name = document.getElementById("facility-count");
        if(name.value === "") {
          var att = document.createAttribute("required");
          name.setAttributeNode(att);
        }
   
    var name = document.getElementById("unitCount");
        if(name.value === "") {
          var att = document.createAttribute("required");
          name.setAttributeNode(att);
        }
   
    }
    
    </script>
```

```html
<html> 
<body class="bg-light">

 
<h2 style="font-family: montserrat;font-size:26px;font-weight: 600;z-index: 1;color: white;text-align:center;margin-top:240px;">Cost Savings Calculator </h2>
        <center style="">
          
            <div class="card col-lg-9 innerBox" style="margin-top:50px;border-radius:22px 22px 0px 0px;">

                <div class="card-body" style="
    margin-bottom: 20px;">

                    <div>

                        


 <div class="tab">
                           
                              
   <div class="float-start backArrowBtn">
                                    <img src=" backArrow.png" height="30px" width="30px">
                                </div>
   
     
  
 <div class="form-group"  style="align-content:center;margin-bottom: 20px;">
                                    <label id="label" for="orgName" >Organization Name</label>
                               
<input type="text"  class="form-control w-50 form-control-lg" name="organization-name" id="orgName"
                                        placeholder="We Care" required>

                                  
                                    


                            </div>     

                                <button  name="next" class="next btn btn-primary" onclick="checkValue()">Next</button>
                       
                          </div>
    
 
                        <div class="tab">
                            
                          
                                <img src=" backArrow.png" height="30px" width="30px" name="previous"
                                    class="previous action-button-previous float-start backArrowBtn">
                                
                          <div class="form-group"  style="align-content:center;margin-bottom: 20px;">
                                    <label id="label" for="facilityCount">Number of Facilities</label>
                                   
                                     
                                  
                                  <input type="number" name="ffname" class="form-control w-50 form-control-lg" id="facility-count"
                                        placeholder="1000" required >
                               
                      </div>
                                <button  name="next" class="next btn btn-primary"  onclick = "checkValue()"style="font-family:montserrat;padding-top: 0px;font-size: 17px;font-weight: 400;padding-right: 0px;padding-bottom: 0px;width: 128px;height: 49px;padding-left: 0px;margin-top:3%;">Next</button>
                           
                                  </div>
                        
 <div class="tab">
                          
                                <img src=" backArrow.png" height="30px" width="30px" name="previous"
                                    class="previous action-button-previous float-start backArrowBtn">
                                
   <div class="form-group"  style="align-content:center;margin-bottom: 20px;">
                                    <label id="label2" for="unitCount" >Average number of units per facility<br>
                                    <span class="extraLabel"  style="font-family: montserrat;font-size:20px;font-weight: 600;margin-right:0%">(Optional: Hospitals Only)</span></label><br>
                                  
                                  <input type="number" name="units-per-facility"class="form-control w-50 form-control-lg" id="unitCount"
                                        placeholder="1000" required style="font-family: montserrat;border:0.5px solid;border-radius:10px;">
                               
                      </div>
                                <button type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-primary"  onclick = "checkValue()"style="font-family:montserrat;padding-top: 0px;font-size: 17px;font-weight: 400;padding-right: 0px;padding-bottom: 0px;width: 128px;height: 49px;padding-left: 0px;margin-top:3%;">Next</button><br>
                              
                          </div>
 
                                <div class="col-sm-7">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        


                                        <input type="text" name="name-a"class="form-control w-75 formInput" 
                                            placeholder="Name" id="orgName" style="border: solid 1px #0b13a2;border-radius: 9px;font-family: montserrat;font-size: 15px; ">
                                        <input type="text" name="titlee" class="form-control w-75 formInput" 
                                            placeholder="Title" style="border: solid 1px #0b13a2;border-radius: 9px;font-family: montserrat;font-size: 15px;">
                                        <input type="text" name="company" class="form-control w-75 formInput"
                                            placeholder="Company Name"  style="border: solid 1px #0b13a2;border-radius: 9px;font-family: montserrat;font-size: 15px;">
                                        <input type="email" name="emails" class="form-control w-75 formInput"
                                            placeholder="Email" style="border: solid 1px #0b13a2;border-radius: 9px;font-family: montserrat;font-size: 15px;">
                                       
                                      
                                           
                                       
                                           
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"  class="btn btn-primary" style="font-family:montserrat;font-size: 17px;font-weight: 400;width: 75%;height: 49px;" />
                                      
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                  </div>



                            
                    
                     
                </div>
                
   
                 
                
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="progress col-lg-9" style="height: 5px;">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%; background-color: #0B13A2;"
                aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
        </div>
      

    </center>
    </html>
```

Comment: Inside the chechValue function, you declare the same variable 'name' 3 times inside single scope, that is bad, rename them or something. Also, not sure why are you attaching the 'required' attribute like this, why not simply do it in the elements itself?

Comment: @PavelHoryna doesn't work even after renaming the variables. in My CSS i have set 'tab' to 'display: none', with this property step form display perfectly in steps. But when i remove it or change 'none' to anything else then the whole form breaks into  a single But then page but validation starts to work.